# Regex match a CSV file

Tags: c#, java, .net, regex

I am trying to create a regex to match a CSV file of records in the form of:

```
optional value, , ,, again some value; this is already, next record;
```

Now there is an upper limit of commas (10) separating attributes of each record and unlimited number of `;` separating each record. Values might or might not be present. I am unexperienced with regex and my effort is rather futile so far. Please help. If necessary, I will include more details.

**EDIT**

I want to verify that the file is in the required form and get the number of records in it.

Comment: What do you want the result to be?

Comment: If you have a large set of records, I suggest not using Regex as its performance is dwarfed by manual, smart parsing, unless you're just interested in learning Regex.

Comment: Does the file contain escaped commas or semicolons, e.g. `a,b,"c1,;;c2",d;`? If not, you can split by `;` for each record, and then split by `,` (or simply count the semicolons).

Comment: @BeemerGuy: Thank you for suggestion. I was using that (the same thing as also Kobi proposed), but boss wants to see a regex.. Also I am quite interested in. There should be never more than 500 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to use regular expressions for this? Might be a little bit overkill. I'd just perform one String.Split() to get the records, then another String.Split() on each record to get the values. Also rather easy to get the number of elements etc. then.

If you really want to use Regexps, I'd use two steps again:
`/(.*?);/` to get the datasets;
`/(.*?)[,;]/` to get the values.

Could probably be done with one regexp as well but I'd consider this overkill (as you'd have to find the sub matches etc. identify their parent record, etc.).

Escaped characters would be another thing but rather similar to do: e.g. `/(.*?[^\\]);/`

Comment: Totally agree, regex, especially with backreference tend to be slow, so better use split.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
bool isvalid = csv.Split(';')
                    .Select(c => c.Split(',')
                        .Count())
                    .Distinct()
                    .Count() == 1;
```

Comment: Parsing a CSV is not as simple as splitting it by a single char.

Comment: Why not ? - its what the OP wants

Comment: It really depends on the data expected in the CSV. Once you've got strings it gets a little bit more complicated as you can't just split it then.

Comment: I really don't understand your reservations. A CSV is a list of string separated by commas - it really doesn't get simpler than that

Comment: An example dataset could be this:
    55,192,139290, "Wow, great story! Please provide us more!"
Comment formatting breaks it, but in this example you'd get 5 values where the fourth includes '"Wow' - not the whole text string,

Answer (score 0):

Reminds me to the famous article form Coding Horror: [Regular Expressions: Now You Have Two Problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html).

[FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) saved my day when dealing with CSV or other text format.